# Inner method of directive is not calling the parent method (also no error in console)

Tags: angularjs

I have a html defined like this

```
<div class="modal" my-modal my-modal-id="delete-users-modal" my-modal-title="Delete Confirmation">
    <div class="modal-body">
        my body
    </div>
    <button ng-click="confirmDelete() class="tick-icon">Delete</button>
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="cancel-icon">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The directive I have created to convert that chunk to my desired html is like this

```
.directive('myModal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            myModalId: '@',
            myModalTitle: '@'            
        },
        compile: function(tEle, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {
            var $oEle = $(tEle.context);
            var $body = $(tEle.context).find('.modal-body');
            tEle.find('.modal-body').html($body.html());
            tEle.removeClass('hide');

            var $footer = tEle.find('.modal-footer');
            var $btns = $oEle.find('button');
            $btns.each(function(i,o){
                var $o = $(o);
                var c = $o.attr('class');
                var t = $o.html();
                $o.html('');
                $o.removeClass().addClass('btn btn-primary ok-btn');
                $o.append('<span class="mct-icons ' + c + '"></span>');
                $o.append('<span class="btn-title">' + t + '</span>')
                $footer.append($o);
            });
        },
        template: '<div id="{{myModalId}}" class="modal">' +
            '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                    '<div class="modal-header">' +
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>' +
                        '<h1 class="modal-title">{{myModalTitle}}</h1>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-body">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

The problem is the method confirmDelete() is not firing on click of Delete button, this method is defined in parent scope. How to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you don't have `confirDelete` typo in you original code

Comment: Is it because it says `confirDelete()` and not `confirmDelete()`? - missing letter "m"

Comment: it was a typing mistake in question is fix now.

Comment: I see no role of the directive here. Does removing the directive from the DOM fix the issue? I can't see how it is important to the question here.

Comment: @callmekatootie why there is no role of directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using isolate scope, but you haven't declared any attribute for your delete function, so your directive doesn't have access to it in the controller.

From the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> The & binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an
>   expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time.
>   Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which
>   contains a function call.

So, here you can use the `&` binding type to call the function in the context of the original scope:

```
scope: {
    myModalId: '@',
    myModalTitle: '@',
    delete: '&'
}
```

This requires that you also pass in the function name in the function declaration in your HTML:

```
<div class="modal" my-modal="" delete="confirmDelete()"
my-modal-id="delete-users-modal" my-modal-title="Delete Confirmation">
```

Then you can call the function from the isolate scope by the name you gave it in your `scope: { ... }` directive setting:

```
<button ng-click="delete()" class="tick-icon">Delete</button>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8yocQxtCZCGl2zLKz8W?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile contents using the parent scope:

```
.directive('myModal', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            myModalId: '@',
            myModalTitle: '@'            
        },
        link: function(scope, tEle, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {
            var $oEle = $(tEle.context);

            $compile($oEle.find('.modal-body'))(scope.$parent, function($body) {
                tEle.find('.modal-body').html($body);
                tEle.removeClass('hide');
            });

            $compile($oEle.find('button'))(scope.$parent, function($btns) {
                var $footer = tEle.find('.modal-footer');
                $btns.each(function(i,o){
                    var $o = $(o);
                    var c = $o.attr('class');
                    var t = $o.html();
                    $o.html('');
                    $o.removeClass().addClass('btn btn-primary ok-btn');
                    $o.append('<span class="mct-icons ' + c + '"></span>');
                    $o.append('<span class="btn-title">' + t + '</span>')
                    $footer.append($o);
                });
            });
        },
        template: '<div id="{{myModalId}}" class="modal">' +
            '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                    '<div class="modal-header">' +
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>' +
                        '<h1 class="modal-title">{{myModalTitle}}</h1>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-body">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: You can think of isolate scope as a firewall, and this (compiling with $parent) is like turning off the firewall, whereas using `@`, `&`, and `=` in a `scope: { ... }` block is like poking a few holes through. Might as well set `scope: false`, right?

Comment: Notice that I'm not using the parent scope, but only passing it to the `$compile`. The directive code is not dependent on the parent scope, it doesn't read data from it. The goal is to separate the directive's scope from the transcluded one - directive doesn't care what's inside, it just compiles it (flexibility). BTW another solution is to use `transcludeFn` which does the same stuff, but then you have to struggle with returned data (jqLite collection).